# How does Jgit obtain the code diff information of the historical commitid that has been rebased?

Tags: java, git, rebase, git-commit, jgit

A branch has been rebased or reseted, and I want to get the code version of a certain commit before rebase. When I query the commit, an error will be reported

`org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing commit b83a1c25a8a630f293fe18090cff1f9a640f0246 at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:145) at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.getCachedBytes(RevWalk.java:1164) at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit.parseHeaders(RevCommit.java:151) at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.markStart(RevWalk.java:325) at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LogCommand.add(LogCommand.java:343) at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LogCommand.add(LogCommand.java:180)`

This is part of my code

```
ObjectId objectId = git.getRepository().resolve(currentCommitId);
        if (objectId == null) {
            logger.error("current commitId is null ，commitId:{}", currentCommitId);
        }
        RevCommit currentCommit = git.log().add(objectId).setMaxCount(1).call().iterator().next();

        String baseMasterCommit = "";
        baseMasterCommit = this.getBaseMasterCommit(git, currentCommit, currentCommitId, baseMasterCommit);
```

I tried using git reflog, but after changing the server, the git reflog operation could not find any commit information.

Comment: If that commit existed in that repo that you are working on, then it has been garbage collected. Rebased commits do _not_ link to their original commits (other than perhaps in the comment.... _as a comment_, so no real link there) so it's no surprise that commit might have ended up in `/dev/null`, so to speak.

Comment: Just for this situation, if you want to get the historical commit information code remotely, what is the way to get it?

Comment: Like, that commit is still reachable through a remote repo? I would _assume_ you still need the information in the local repo for jgit to be able to use it so, you need to *fetch that commit from the remote*, then you should ready to go.

Comment: The git fetch command will only obtain all commit information in the current state of the remote warehouse. It will not obtain the commit history before the rebase operation. When you perform a git rebase operation on a branch, Git takes every commit on that branch since the upstream branch and reapplies them on the upstream branch, generating a new, identical set of changes. This means that rebase creates new commits and replaces old commits, and these old commits are only deleted by the garbage collector when no other references point to them.

Comment: I know everything you are saying there.... However, rebasing _locally_ won't remove _automagically_ those original commits from a remote branch if they were already there, unless you force-pushef, under normal conditions. Did you force-push after rebasing? I don't know. Even if you did, is there another reference in the remote repo that might expose the old commit? I don't know. Is there? Let me try again: *if the commit is reachable from a remote repo*, you will still need to fetch to be able to use it on the local repo.

Comment: Even if the commit is not reachable on a remote repo where it _used_ to be, you might still get away with it if you have access to the repo and create a reference to that commit *if it hasn't been garbage collected*. Of course, that's the kind of things you can do with a repo you hold yourself.... With providers like GitHub and such, I don't know what trickery might be used to get a reference to an _old_ history of a branch.